# Error on AngularJS : $injector:unpr Unknown Provider:

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

i'm trying to make an angular app following thinster.io tutorial(https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial), i restarted and restarted again after many erros, this is a new one :

```
Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: patientProvider <- patient <- PatientsCtrl
```

Here is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ka0U3mixzNx14rjPpA5d?p=preview) for code.

I already tried solution for this error, that i found on stackoverflow, but without success...

Does anybody have an idea ?

Comment: The plunkr is not working, your javascript file is not being loaded. And your angular module `demo` does not exist, it is called `psytools`.

Comment: That error mean you didn't have patient provider. Please tell we know you idea 

```
    ['$scope', 'patients', 'patient', function($scope, patients, patient)
```
 What is patient?

Comment: That i don't understand is my code is the same that this one (https://github.com/jermspeaks/Thinkster-MEAN-Tutorial/blob/master/public/javascripts/angularApp.js), and they don't have patient service, even if i undestood that it's missing here (patients for posts, and patient for post)

Comment: kuhnroyal --> it's a paste mistake, i just changed psytools fort demo.

Answer (score 0):

the service patient is missing try adding that service and then try even in error it clearly shows the problem is with patient service.